# String tokenizer method

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, tokenize

Consider strings with this format:

```
id-string1-string2-string3.extension
```

where id, string1, string2 and string3 can be string of variable length, and extension is an image extension type.

For example, two possible strings could be:

```
Il2dK-Ud2d9-Kod2d-d9dwo.jpg

j54fwf3da-7jrg-9eujodww-kio98ujk.png
```

I need tokenizer method in **JavaScript** for an **express/nodejs** API that takes these strings in input and outputs an object with this format:

```
{a: id-string1-string2, b: string3, c: extension}
```

For the example strings this tokenizer should then output:

```
{a: Il2dK-Ud2d9-Kod2d, b: d9dwo, c: jpg}

{a: j54fwf3da-7jrg-9eujodww, b: kio98ujk, c: png}
```

I think this can be done with regex. I tried to use the following regex **match(/[^-]+/g)**, but this tokenize every substring, I need a way to skip the first 2 char "-" but couldn't find it out.

Do you have any ideas? Or could you provide me a better solution instead of using regex? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`spit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) as:

```js
const str = 'Il2dK-Ud2d9-Kod2d-d9dwo.jpg';
const [restStr, c] = str.split('.');
const [a, b] = restStr.split(/-([a-z0-9]+$)/);
const result = { a, b, c };
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use a pattern with capture groups:

```
^(?<a>[^\s-]+(?:-[^\s-]+)*)-(?<b>[^\s.-]+)\.(?<c>\w+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<a>[^\s-]+(?:-[^\s-]+)*)` Named group *a*, match any char except a whitespace char or `-` and optionally repeat `-` and again any char except a whitespace char
- `-` Match literally
- `(?<b>[^\s.-]+)` Named group *b*, match 1+ chars other than `.` `-` or a whitespace char
- `\.` Match `.`
- `(?<c>\w+)` Named group *c*, match 1+ word chars for the extension
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dhPssQ/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?<a>[^\s-]+(?:-[^\s-]+)*)-(?<b>[^\s.-]+)\.(?<c>\w+)$/;
[
  "id-string1-string2-string3.extension",
  "Il2dK-Ud2d9-Kod2d-d9dwo.jpg",
  "j54fwf3da-7jrg-9eujodww-kio98ujk.png",
  "a-b-c",
  "a.b"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m.groups);
  }
});
```

Without named groups, you can use capture groups and create the objects:

```js
const regex = /^([^\s-]+(?:-[^\s-]+)*)-([^\s.-]+)\.(\w+)$/;
[
  "id-string1-string2-string3.extension",
  "Il2dK-Ud2d9-Kod2d-d9dwo.jpg",
  "j54fwf3da-7jrg-9eujodww-kio98ujk.png",
  "a-b-c",
  "a.b"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log({
      "a": m[1],
      "b": m[2],
      "c": m[3]
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To split at the last hyphen or any period:

```
res = str.split(/-(?![^-]*-)|\./);
```

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gDrbLy/1) or [JS demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##LY5Bb8IwDIXv@RXZqek0B1FAUCHgtMPEmRMDqWrSLCGKqyRQpI3f3hmJg/XZ7/nJds2tSW20fYbbahy9zjzlmPiGHwurgHobzPTF6sWZ1PesQ7IYio/iy1dqDwdVqRr2SABVqwGl6w25bjHvhm6mGli6aKDWV4dqGOBisV5d3UX2wRSnNWPPs7LD@Nm0P0LQVPLNlv8yzqN@/kOKTL23WUxA7N6OZzi9Q/n3LSflmpZaDAm9lh6NoABpDyrGxvEf)

- [`(?!` negative lookahead `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [`[^` negated character set `]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- [`|` OR](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)  match any period `\.`

At the position after any hyphen a negative *lookahead* (zero-length assertion/condtion) checks if there is not another hyphen ahead with any amount of non-hyphens in between OR match period.